# How to call a DB2 stored procedure using Visual Basic?

Tags: database, vb.net, stored-procedures, db2

I am trying to call a store procedure in Visual Basic from a DB2 Database.  I want to send the input from a variable as a parameter from my Visual Basic code and take the outputs and put them in variables in my VB code.  Here is my store procedure code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE VendorPROCEDURE (IN p_vendor_name  VARCHAR(50),
                              OUT p_name VARCHAR(25),
                              OUT p_company_name VARCHAR(50),
                              OUT p_address VARCHAR(25),
                              OUT p_csz VARCHAR(50),
                              OUT p_phone CHAR(13))
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
P1: BEGIN
DECLARE v_name VARCHAR(25);
DECLARE v_company_name VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE v_address VARCHAR(25);
DECLARE v_csz VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE v_phone CHAR(13);

SELECT RTRIM(REP_F_NAME || ' ' || REP_L_NAME), COMPANY_NAME, STREET,
RTRIM(CITY || ', ' || STATE || ' ' || VENDOR.ZIP_CODE) AS CSZ, PHONE_NUM
INTO v_name, v_company_name, v_address, v_csz, v_phone
FROM SALES_REP, VENDOR, ZIP
WHERE SALES_REP.REP_NUM = VENDOR.REP_NUM
AND ZIP.ZIP_CODE = VENDOR.ZIP_CODE
AND COMPANY_NAME = p_vendor_name;

SET p_name = v_name;
SET p_company_name = v_company_name;
SET p_address = v_address;
SET p_csz = v_csz;
SET p_phone = v_phone;

END P1
```

In my VB code I am Importing IBM.Data.DB2 and here is the code I have so far:

```
    Dim vendorName As String
    vendorName = Vendor_ComboBox.Text
    cmd = connectionstring.CreateCommand()
    connectionstring.Open()
    Dim trans As DB2Transaction = connectionstring.BeginTransaction()
    cmd.Transaction() = trans
    Dim reader As DB2DataReader
    Dim procName As String = "VENDORPROCEDURE"
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.CommandText = procName
```

I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: Go from here? Try adding `cmd.Execute`. Also, VB is different from VBA. The latter mainly runs in MS Office products. Please tag accordingly.

Comment: add your parameters first param = new sqlparameter("p_vendor_name", <data type>) param.direction = Input cmd.parameters.add(param), and so on, changing the direction for output parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From there you would do something like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("p_vendor_name", DB2DbType.VarChar, 50).Value = vendorName
cmd.Parameters.Add("p_name", DB2DbType.VarChar, 25).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
'Etc.'
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
```

You can then read the result set of the query line by line using that data reader.  You might do this:

```
If reader.HasRows Then
    'Read the data here.'
Else
    'There is no data so act accordingly here.'
End If
```

or you might just do this:

```
While reader.Read()
    'Get data from current row of reader by column name or ordinal here.'
End While
```

In the second case, `Read` returns `False` when there is no more data to read so, if there are no rows, nothing will happen as you'll never enter the loop.